# Using GitHub actions like GitLab CI/CD

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I just started to migrate all my GitLab repositories to GitHub. I wasn't using GitHub for a while so I stumbled over the - at least for me new feature - GitHub Actions.

Since I just started a new project, I wanted to use GitHub Actions for build and deploy my new application. I've really no idea what I'm doing wrong, I'll attach my workflow file below.

What I want to achieve is, everytime I push to a branch that's not my master and that hasn't the prefix 'release/', I want to execute this build and deploy for my development system. Later I will also setup the same script but for a staging (pre production) system ONLY if I push into a branch with the prefix 'release/' and indeed the same a thrid time for production for the master branch only.

What I'm wondering about is, the actions get - at least for my understanding - executed sporadically. I want an behaviour like I had in GitLab: Everytime I push a feature branch or whatever from my local working machine, the development pipeline should get executed. Then I'll create a pull request. Only if the pipeline was successful, I want to be able to merge. After the merge into a branch (for example feature/... into develop), I would like to automatically execute the pipeline for development.

I'm not even sure if this is possible. Maybe I also didn't understood the concept of actions correctly.

```
name: Publish Development
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
      - '!master'
      - '!release/**'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '**'
      - '!master'
      - '!release/**'

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Build and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
      - name: install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: install dependencies
        run: npm --prefix ./functions install ./functions
      - name: deploy to firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Well it turned out that I just started to try new technology during some service interruption. [GitHub was experiencing some issues in their infrastructure](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/6tcfpztf6j9m). Its working now as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out that I just started to try new technology during some service interruption. GitHub was experiencing some issues in their infrastructure. Its working now as expected.